# flask-login can not be used in Blueprint object?

Tags: flask, blueprint, flask-login

I have a question regarding flask-login and blueprint.

admin.py

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.setup_app(admin)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    return User.query.get(int(userid))

@admin.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #####user validation####
        login_user(user)
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('admin/login.html', login_form=login_form)
```

run.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(blog_config)
app.register_blueprint(admin)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I post a form, and use login_user(user), an error occurred.

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'
```

Then I try to use flask-login in run.py, It works fine.

run.py

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.setup_app(admin)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    return User.query.get(int(userid))
```

So, What I want to ask is,flask-login can not be used in Blueprint object?
THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why it called `setup_app`

Just move initialization to your `run.py` and pass app as parameter
And login itself can stay inside admin blueprint

Answer (score 30):

It is also possible to LoginManager.setup_app() on Blueprint's registration:

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()

@admin.record_once
def on_load(state):
    login_manager.init_app(state.app)
```

on_load will be run when the Blueprint is first registered to the app.