# Flask-Login extension, enabling login on modules

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have an app, which is quite big, so it's divided into modules and use `blueprints`, `add_url_rule` for routing to various modules. Everything works fine and as intented.

The problem is, I need to use the Flask-Login (https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#api-documentation), from the documentaion. I could only find how to protect views using `decorators`, for which the app should have routes set using the `app.route('/home')`. But like I already mentioned, I'm using `blueprints` and `add_url_rule`.

EDIT: The answer @Mark Hildreth edited into this question, is the required solution. Thank you.

Comment: @AjKumar There's not much I could try, but I did try doing `login_required(func)` inside a loop, where `func` is the `view function` of each module. It didn't do anything, no errors either.

Comment: maybe this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273499/flask-login-can-not-be-used-in-blueprint-object

Comment: @AjKumar Yes, I did see that post prior to posting my question. The suggested solution in the answer is deprecated. And, it's just the main `app` variable. I have multiple modules, eg: Add, View, Edit etc, all registered as different blueprints.

Comment: Can you share at least 1 example of your blueprint view and inits ? You should still be able to use blueprint and flask-login.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that "the app should have routes set using the `app.route('/home')`"? They probably just used that as the example because that's how a simple Flask app works. Have you tried putting the decorator on the blueprint's view function? As @codegeek asked, can you show this attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example with decorators:

```
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    pass
```

is equivalent to this example without decorators:

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', login_required(index))
```