# How do I handle login in flask with multiple blueprints?

Tags: python, flask-login, flask

I have multiple blueprints that needs to be integrated into a single app. I'm using `flask-login` to handle logins. However I'm confused on how to handle the `LoginManager()` and the `.user_loader` for my blueprints.

This is my current file structure.

```
system/
     run.py
     config.py
     app/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views/
             blueprint1.py
             blueprint2.py
        static/
        templates/
              <templates>
```

What's the correct way to implement them? Do I just call them at the `__init__.py` and import the login manager variable at the blueprints? or Do I need to call them individually in the blueprints?

Hopefully I'm able to portray the question clearly. Thank you for reading and answering

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must understand that for one application you must use one login manager no matter how many blueprints you use (of course there can be specific exceptions for example when blueprints are independent, but in this case you probably can't use `flask-login`). Because:

1. You have 1 entry point
2. If user is not logged in, he will be redirected to login/registration page
3. You have 1 user loader

How login manager works:

1. It registers `current_user` in request context
2. `before_request` reads your session, gets user id, loads the user with `user_loader` and set it to `current_user` or `AnonymousUser`
3. When you visit  the private page, `login_required` checks `current_user.is_authenticated()` else redirects to login page
4. On login, it adds user id to the session

So you must initialize only one login manager instance for flask application and then use `login_required` and `current_user` in all your blueprints.

Comment: It means i can't use login_manager for multiple instance? Like admin-page and user-page ?

Answer (score 7):

This is how I have handled it:

This is where I am initialising everything:

```
import logging
import logging.config

import flask
import flask.globals as flask_global
import flask_login

from config import flask as flask_config
from rest.api import dashboard
from rest.api.util import login_decorator

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# app
flask_app = flask.Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.from_object(flask_config)

# login manager needs be set before blueprint registration
login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(flask_app)

flask_app.register_blueprint(dashboard.blueprint)


# setting blueprint specific login view
# login_manager.login_view = "login"


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """
    This will be used many times like on using current_user
    :param user_id: username
    :return: user or none
    """
    # http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2012/4/7/current-blueprint/#44814417e8289f5f5bb9683d416ee1ee
    blueprint = flask_global.current_app.blueprints[request.blueprint]

    if hasattr(blueprint, load_user):
        return blueprint.load_user(user_id)

    # https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works
    return None
```

Here is my blueprint with its own handling of login:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import flask
import flask_login
from flask import Blueprint

from core.models.profile import Agent
from core.utils import thread_local
from rest.api.util import login_decorator

blueprint = Blueprint('human', __name__, url_prefix='/human')


def load_user(user_id):
    """
    This will be used many times like on using current_user
    :param user_id: username
    :return: user or none
    """
    agent = None
    try:
        agent = Agent.objects.get(username=user_id)
    except:
        # https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works
        pass
    return agent


@blueprint.record_once
def on_load(state):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/20172064/742173

    :param state: state
    """
    blueprint.load_user = load_user
    state.app.login_manager.blueprint_login_views[blueprint.name] = 'human.login'


@blueprint.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@login_decorator.login_not_required
def login():
    username = flask.request.args.get('username')
    password = flask.request.args.get('password')
    try:
        agent = Agent.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        return 'Invalid username'

    if not agent.check_password(password):
        return 'Invalid password'

    flask_login.login_user(agent)

    return 'Valid login'


@blueprint.route("/logout")
def logout():
    flask_login.logout_user()
    return 'Logout done'


@blueprint.before_request
def before_request():
    agent = flask_login.current_user
    # https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#anonymous-users
    is_logged_in = agent.get_id() is not None

    login_not_required = getattr(flask.current_app.view_functions[flask.request.endpoint], 'login_not_required', False)
    is_static_resource_call = flask.request.endpoint.startswith('static/')

    if is_static_resource_call or is_logged_in or login_not_required:
        if is_logged_in:
            thread_local.set_current_brand_id(agent.brand_id)
    else:
        flask.abort(401)
        # if we want to redirect to some page then we can use this. The appropriate login_view should be set
        # return flask.current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still faces this challenge due to the documentation not being so clear, here is a solution

In your case, you need to place the login manager declaration in the same file as the flask app instance. This is commonly an `__init__.py` file with the `app = Flask(__name__).` 
At the top, import LoginManager class

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

Then tie it to the app instance.

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

(This was not asked but just incase someone needs it) Lets say you have admins and normal users and you are authenticating from different tables:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    x = Users.query.get(str(user_id))
    if x == None:
        x = Admins.query.get(str(user_id))
    return x
```

Finally after importing blueprints you can define the login views for each in a dictionary

```
login_manager.blueprint_login_views = {
    'admin': '/admin/login',
    'site': '/login',
}
```

Since you tied the login manager to the flask app instance, there is no need of importing it into any blueprint

Comment: Just a note, query.get() is the same as "where primary_key_field = user_id" so if you have >= the number of Users as you do Admins then this will never search the admin table assuming both are auto-incrementing int PKs

Comment: Nice point. Never thought of that because all my primary keys are usually uuid4().

Comment: Hi, I am assuming here that you have different logins for site and admin.  What if I have only one type of user (and multiple blueprints)?  would this method work?

Comment: Yes, it should work. You would only need to remove the if statement querying the admin table.

Comment: Will this work for a spa (single-page application)? Or is the `login_manager.blueprint_login_views` exclusively for returning views, i.e. html?

Comment: If creating a SPA in react / other, it might be better if you implemented a REST login endpoint for token based auth.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is unclear and I will put down what I come up with after spending some time researching.

You only need to define login_manager once in the flask app.py and init_app.
Then at each blueprint, add `from flask_login import login_required` at top and use the @login_required as usual. Turns out it can be used without stating the login_manager.

### Code example (app with single blueprint)

#### app.py

```
import flask
from flask import redirect, url_for
import flask_login

from blueprint.secret import secret_bp
from model.user import User

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(secret_bp, url_prefix="/secret")

login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if flask.request.method == "GET":
        return "<form action='/login' method='POST'><input type='text' name='user'><button type='submit'>Submit</button></form>"

    user = flask.request.form.get('user')
    if user == "user":
        # Login and validate the user.
        # user should be an instance of your `User` class
        flask_login.login_user(user)

        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')

        return flask.redirect(next or flask.url_for('index'))
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))

@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return "Admin page"

@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    # do stuff
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

#### secret.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
from flask_login import login_required

secret_bp = Blueprint('secret', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@secret_bp.route('/noneed')
def no_need():
    return "You can see this without login."

@secret_bp.route('/needlogin')
@login_required
def show():
    return "can't see this if not login"
```

As expected, /secret/noneed can be access without login and /secret/needlogin will redirect you with the function stated with @unauthorized_handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the application factory pattern, you have blueprints and you don't know where to put the `login_manager` `user_loader` function, you can put it in the create app function.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from module import your_blueprint

...
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    app.register_blueprint(your_blueprint, url_prefix="/home")
    ...
    return app
```

Hope this helps