# Flask and blueprints - whats the deal with @login_required?

Tags: python, flask

So I created a bluiprint and decorated with @login_required.  Auth, Users etc are on my main views.py. If I remove @login_required my code workes.  But if I add I am redirected to login page.  Auth does work prior to moving the code to a blueprint.  So how do I import into my blueprint the objects needed for auth?

Here is my blueprint

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,jsonify,Response
from flask import make_response,session,redirect,url_for,g
from flask.ext.security import Security
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required, UserMixin,confirm_login,fresh_login_required
from flask_security import auth_token_required, http_auth_required
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth # sudo pip install flask-httpauth
from flask import Blueprint
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

delstack = Blueprint('/delstack/<stack_id>', __name__)
@delstack.route('/delstack/<stack_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@login_required
def delstack_route(stack_id): 

    jd = {'status':'ok'}
    data = json.dumps(jd) 
    resp = Response(data, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273499/flask-login-can-not-be-used-in-blueprint-object solved my problem